# Intervention image blurry after resize

Tags: php, laravel-5, imagick, intervention

I've set the driver to 'imagick' and here's the code that resizes the image:

```
Route::get('something', function()
{
    $img = Image::make(storage_path('assets/someimage.jpg'))->resize(1000, null, function($cons){
        $cons->aspectRatio();
    });

    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

Original image is 1944 x 2300.

And the quality loss is quite prominent - image becomes a bit blurry.

Is there anything I need to configure or can I output an image a different way perhaps?

---

Below is the image resized with `Photoshop` using `Save for web -> JPG with quality set to 80`

[image]

And here is the same image resized using intervention image:

[image]

The second one is a bit blurry if you look closely.

Comment: Can you post some example before and after images?

Comment: Done. Hope I'll get this resolved..

Comment: I don't believe the image is blurred - instead it appears to have the same detail, but at a much lower contrast. e.g. if you compare some of the single pixel specs in the 'blurred' picture, they are still single pixels, just much less visible. This is likely to be a colorspace thing....can you post the original image to a place like drop box, that doesn't resample the image.